# Prove factorial?

Tags: proof-writing

$k! > \frac{k}{2}^\frac{k}{2} \text{ for } k\in N$

I'm not sure how to prove this, is it valid to rewrite it as?:

$(2k)! > k^k \text{ for } k\in N$

Edit: I think I proved it...

$(2k)!=1\cdot2...k\cdot(k+1)...(k+k)>k!k^k$

$(2k)!>k!k^k>k^k$

Comment: It would be better to define a new variable $m=k/2$ and write it as $(2m)!\gt m^m$ to avoid confusion, but the expressions are equivalent.  Now think about the largest $m$ factors on the left.

Comment: No, it's valid to rewrite it as $(2(k!))^2 > k^k$. Note that $(2(k!))^2$ is very different from and much smaller than $(2k)!$.